# Listing and linking files that are larger than X by creation date in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am listing files and linking them using php on a set of static HTML pages with the following script:

```
<?php

$dir="./content"; // Directory where files are stored

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false) {
        //this kills the annoying .. and . directory listing
        if($filename == ".." || $filename == ".") continue; ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a></p>
<?php
}
closedir($dir_list);
}
?>
```

What I would like to do now is list files that are larger than a certain file size (i.e. files larger than 35 bytes) and order them by creation date (newest to oldest).

Your help and expertise would be greatly appreciated. Apologies in advance about the code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) to check the size of the file and [filectime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) to get the creation date. Hope that gives you some direction.

```
if(filesize($filename) >= YOUR_LIMIT){
    //show file
}
```

To sort, you could insert all files into an array. Something like this:

```
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false){
  $arr[filectime($filename)] = $filename;
}
```

Then sort with [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php):

```
ksort($arr);
```

Then loop them out:

```
foreach ($arr as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Looks like that function returns the actual size. However, I am attempting to filter the listing by filesize.

Looking into it now... let's see if I can come up with the code myself. Thank you for your reply.